What is the difference between these Nerd Font types: mono, propo, script?
I want to install Nerd Fonts. I can install them through scoop. I added its bucket (scoop bucket add nerd-fonts) and when I want to install FiraCode, I get the following options:
scoop search fira
FiraCode-NF-Mono  3.2.1   nerd-fonts
FiraCode-NF-Propo 3.2.1   nerd-fonts
FiraCode-NF       3.2.1   nerd-fonts
FiraCode-Script   0.0.28  nerd-fonts
FiraCode          6.2     nerd-fonts

What is the difference between the base NF, mono, propo, and script versions?
There is a version without any suffix avaiable (FiraCode). Am I right to assume that this is just the original font without any Nerd Font glyphs included?
What are the differences for the variants? Which are their use cases?
Which should I install when I want to use the font for coding in an IDE and terminal?

Just from the names, I'd guess that -mono was a monospace (all characters fit in the same sized block) version, -propo is proportionally-spaced (each letter takes up as much space as it needs), and -script is probably a cursive-oid version.

Generally, you install them all, so you have support for the different versions. Sometimes you just see one font and by selecting a property it automatically switches to the other font.

You can easily verify yourself what each JSON package definition in the bucket does:

FiraCode-NF-Mono downloads the whole .zip from official Nerd Fonts repository, as defined in automatically updated for future versions url property. Then it runs a PowerShell script to filter the NerdFontMono- files and install them either globally or for the user.
likewise, FiraCode-NF-Propo filters the NerdFontPropo- version
FiraCode-NF basically installs all the font files, as it filters by NerdFont- that all .ttf files contain.
FiraCode-Script downloads from a different repository: https://github.com/DanielAtKrypton/Fira-Code-Script It's a version apparently more suitable for development, but it's very outdated so it's unlikely you want to use it.
lastly FiraCode downloads the original non-patched font as you thought


As for which font is the most suitable for you, there's a short summary on the patched font's repository pages:


If you are limited to monospaced fonts (because of your terminal, etc) then pick a font with Nerd Font Mono (or NFM).
If you want to have bigger icons (usually around 1.5 normal letters wide) pick a font without Mono i.e. Nerd Font (or NF). Most terminals support this, but ymmv.
If you work in a proportional context (GUI elements or edit a presentation etc) pick a font with Nerd Font Propo (or NFP).


So there's no generic answer for "an IDE and terminal". One will support the monospaced fonts better, another will look better with the wider characters. I personally use the non-mono non-proportional font as it looks good in Visual Studio Code and WezTerm. It's best to install the full -NF version and test yourself what fits your apps and taste the most. You might even want to use different versions in different apps.

FiraCode-NF-Mono -> monospace
FiraCode-NF-Propo -> for reading
FiraCode-NF    ->   with additional symbols for displaying in terminal
FiraCode-Script ->  a handwritten version
FiraCode -> base font

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
